# Check if installed apk has obb file

Tags: java, android, apk

I am requesting all installed package on android device and it works OK. But i want to know if installed package has any obb file or not. I know i can check it with `file.exist()`, but is there any better and faster way like `PackageManager.getOBBAPK()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only things i have found is prefer install location that usually is 2. That means mean external storage. If any one has better idea please share with us.